# storing data from looped rows in corresponding colum

Tags: python, excel, selenium, openpyxl

The following program loops through data in  each row in the first column and using selenium gets the corresponding data. The objective is to store the data(from the website) into a particular column in the iterated rows.

```
def voltage(cell):
global counter
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row = 2):
    for cell in row:
        if 'A' in cell.coordinate:
            if cell.value:
                #search unit
                vehicle = cell.value
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , 'select2-search__field')))
                unit = driver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-search__field')
                unit.send_keys(vehicle)
                time.sleep(3)
                unit.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH , '//*[@id="dinp"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td')))
                voltage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dinp"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td').text
                #excel
                sheet[f'H{counter}'] = voltage
                book.save(file)
                time.sleep(2)
    counter =+ 1
```

voltage(cell)

The data being fetched is from a dynamic table
The code runs but with one downside to it, it stores the value of the 1st row in the consecutive 2 rows(value from row one stored in row 1 and row 2) but the values are different for each row.